# Magento REST API - "Specified request cannot be processed" Error

Tags: magento, magento2

I've done some integrations with the Magento REST API successfully, but working with a new customer and I  have created the integration and generated the Access Token with access to All resources. The store is running Magento 2.2.5.

Whenever I make a GET request to download anything (Orders, Customers, Countries etc) I'm getting a 400 error with this response:

```
{
"message" : "Specified request cannot be processed.",
"trace" : null
}
```

I'm currently doing a GET to:

rest/default/V1/directory/countries

but have also tried Orders and Customers with the same result.